# All rows containing missing values while using Matlab knnimpute

Tags: matlab, missing-data, nearest-neighbor

I am using Matlab's knnimpute function to replace missing values. Although the data I have is sufficient to replace the missing values ( no large continuous stream of missing data ), i have the error message "All rows of the input data contains missing values. Unable to impute missing values."

Comment: Please give us your code and your example data! If you have only very few missing values, what is your target for those entries? How should they be derived?

Comment: here's my code: 
DATA = csvread('C:\Users\admin1\Desktop\unclean.csv');
A = reshape(DATA, 24,[]);
B = knnimpute(A);
C = reshape(B, [], 1);
csvwrite('C:\Users\admin1\Desktop\Shah Alam\NO clean.csv',C);

My data is hourly time series so i convert it to a matrix with 24 columns, then i apply knnimpute to find missing values by using the data from the same hour of the day after.